# How to encrypt my remote machine? (Which I access via RDP.)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, security, encryption

I've got a small server, mainly for backup purpose. I store sensitive data there, so I'd like to apply some kind of data encryption. Truecrypt's system encryption would be perfect, except I can't even type my password like this.

Any ideas how to solve this?
(I was thinking about having a TC container, but what about browsers with sync enabled? Just install portable versions into the container too?)

- The way of accessing the machine doesn't matter. Anything is fine as far I can set it up for free. Like installing VNC, SSH (cygwin) and things like that. Even installing Linux is fine if it can do what I want. (Full system encryption.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option I can think of would to to create a second partition. You can then use TrueCrypt to encrypt the entire partition. From there just copy all your sensitive data there. As for programs which don't allow you to choose where they store their data I would suggest using [NTFS Symbolic Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) to redirect them to the encrypted partition.

You could do this using a normal TrueCrypt container but the partition option will allow you to use TrueCrypt's auto-mount option.

I did find [some information](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasetup/thread/91aa8b26-2b09-4e56-955c-679b297832e1/) on moving the entire "User" directory on Windows but it seems to either require a fresh Windows install or a bit of hackery.

Comment: Container it is! So far. :)

Comment: Don't know if it would suit you at all but you could also potentially switch to using a VM and having that encrypted instead.